# io.imread reading some .tif files but not others

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, imread

I am trying to understand an error with a script. I inherited the script from a colleague and I'm trying to get it to work on my machine. I am running it in Python3.3.5 and if preforms some measurement functions on *.tif* files. These are the list of modules I call

```
import matplotlib, copy, skimage, mahotas, os, tifffile
from skimage import io, filter, morphology, draw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
```

The script breaks and throws an error at the line calling the io.imread function on my desire *.tif* files.

```
‘OSError: cannot identify image file’
```

However, when I change the script to open a different tif image file path, it works.  I have not included my code, because it seems that this is an issue with my python setup? I get more errors when I try to run this with Python27. It might be incompatibilities with the modules I’m using? 
Does anyone have any clues for what might cause io.imread to work on some image files but not others? 
The only difference I can think of between the image files is size.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. The skimage function works for 8-bit image files, whereas my files where 16-bit.
Changing the image object from

```
io.imread()
```

to the tifffile function

```
tiff.imread()
```

allowed all of my 16-bit images to be processed. A beginner's mistake, but it took me a bit to remember those differences between the library functions.